# jQuery json from PHP result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this jQuery script

```
var dataString = "class_id="+class_id;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msg) {
        //stuck here
    },
    error: function () {
        showNotification("error", "Could not process at this time, try again later."); //this is a function created by me (which works fine so I just left the code in here)
    }
});
```

my PHP output is something like this

```
echo '{status:1,message:"Success"}';
```

or

```
echo '{status:0,message:"Failure"}';
```

what I am trying to do in jQuery `success: function(...)` part is check if status is 0 or 1 and then show the message.

I tried to do is

```
success: function(text) {
   if(parseInt(text.status) == 1) {
      alert(text.message); // this is the success, the status is 1
   } else {
      alert(text.message); // this is the failure since the status is not 1
   }
}
```

which didn't work, it was only outputing the else statement, even though the status was 1

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post about it, I'll edit it with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.status == 0) {
          alert("Success " + msg.message);
        } else if (msg.status == 1) {
          alert("Error " + msg.message);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        showNotification("error", "Could not process at this time, try again later."); //this is a function created by me (which works fine so I just left the code in here)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP is generating invalid JSON, and shows no sign of setting an appropriate content type header to tell the browser to treat it as JSON in the first place. So first, fix the PHP:

```
header('application/json');
echo json_encode(Array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success"));
```

Then:

```
success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg.message)
},
```

Comment: the problem was unspecified dataType

Comment: @Grigor — `dataType` is how you tell jQuery to ignore the server's content-type header and treat the data as something else. Setting the correct content-type is the better option.

Comment: I tried setting the content-type but it wouldn't work still, and when I set the dataType it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode(Array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success"));
```

**JS**

Inside your call back function use

```
success: function (msg) {
    $.parseJSON(msg);
    alert(msg.message);
}
```

The `parseJSON` will convert the json string returned/echoed by PHP in to json object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify in $.ajax the type 'json' data passed to response handler is treated as string. While if you specify 'json'  dataType parameter you can use:

```
msg.status
```

and

```
msg.message
```

As a hint i suggest in php to use the json_encode function to generate json output.